# How to stop animation from occuring at the start

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following SVG for a circle.

```
    <div class="container">
            <div class="switch">
                <svg id="circle" width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 500 500" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="250" fill="black"/>
                </svg>
                <svg id="back_holder" width="465" height="169.5" viewBox="0 0 620 226" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <rect width="620" height="226" rx="113" fill="white"/>
                </svg>
            </div>
    </div>
```

And it is inside a div and a black holder that I have provided for it. And here is the CSS I am using.

```
#circle {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 40%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: circleAnimRev 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
}

#back_holder {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

.circleAnimated {
    animation: circleAnim 0.3s ease-in-out forwards !important;
}

@keyframes circleAnim {
    form {
        left: 40%;
    } to {
        left: 60%;
    }
}

@keyframes circleAnimRev {
    from {
        left: 60%;
    } to {
        left: 40%;
    }
}
```

I am trying to add the .circleAnimated property and assigning it using JS so that I will be able to make a switch animation. What the trouble is that I am not able to get any way to make it properly. So I did this.

```
const circle = document.getElementById('circle');
circle.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    circle.classList.toggle("circleAnimated");
});
```

And this works properly but what the problem is that when I load the page the reverse animation plays first and then it goes normal.

Is there any way so that I can stop that very first animation from playing first, I only want it to play when the circle is clicked after the first animation.

Comment: Remove this `animation: circleAnimRev 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;` from your styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line `animation: circleAnimRev 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;` from css. Make a separate class for `reverse animation` and alternatively add the `circleAnimated` and `circleAnimRev` classes on button click.

```js
const circle = document.getElementById('circle');
circle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const currClass = circle.classList[0];
  if (currClass == "circleAnimated") {
    circle.classList.remove('circleAnimated');
    circle.classList.add('circleAnimRev');
  } else {
    circle.classList.remove('circleAnimRev');
    circle.classList.add('circleAnimated');
  }
});
```

```css
#circle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* animation: circleAnimRev 0.3s ease-in-out forwards; */
}

#back_holder {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.circleAnimated {
  animation: circleAnim 0.3s ease-in-out forwards !important;
}

.circleAnimRev {
  animation: circleAnimRev 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes circleAnim {
  form {
    left: 40%;
  }
  to {
    left: 60%;
  }
}

@keyframes circleAnimRev {
  from {
    left: 60%;
  }
  to {
    left: 40%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="switch">
    <svg id="circle" width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 500 500" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="250" fill="black"/>
            </svg>
    <svg id="back_holder" width="465" height="169.5" viewBox="0 0 620 226" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <rect width="620" height="226" rx="113" fill="white"/>
            </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot that worked, perfectly. What I was thinking instead too like how about I add a boolean and set it to false and then use it to do the same logic?!